# socket.io slow response after using nginx

Tags: node.js, proxy, nginx, socket.io

I have used my local setup without nginx to serve my node.js application, I was using socket.io and the performance was quite good.

Now, I am using nginx to proxy my request and I see that **socket.io has a huge response time**, which means my page is getting rendered fast, but the data rendered by socket.io is order of magnitude slower than before.

I am using NGINX 1.1.16 and here is the conf,

```
gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Even though everything is working, I have 2 issues,

1. socket.io response is slower than before. **With NGINX, the response
   time is around 12-15sec** and without, it's hardly 300ms. tried this
   with apache benchmark.
2. I see this message in the console, which was not there before using
   NGINX,

   ```
   [2012-03-08 09:50:58.889] [INFO] console -    warn  - 'websocket connection invalid'
   ```

Answer (score 6):

You could try adding:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

See [the docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_buffering) for info, but I've seen some chatter on various forums that buffering increases the response time in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Is the console message from NGINX or SocketIO?

NGINX proxy does not talk HTTP 1.1, which may be why web socket is not working.

Update:
Found a blog post about it: http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets

A proposed solution:
http://blog.mixu.net/2011/08/13/nginx-websockets-ssl-and-socket-io-deployment/

Comment: The message is from node.js application (not from NGINX).. So do you mean to say that I am not getting the data through websocket, but through some other transport mechanism ? how can i check that ?

Comment: Yea, that make sense. Yes, you are not getting data through web socket, but NGINX is still trying to forward the packet even when it does not understand it..which it incorrectly converts a HTTP 1.1 web socket request to HTTP 1.0. To socket.io, this is broken.

Comment: The workaround is to configure NGINX instead of working on the application layer, it should work on the transport layer. The detailed instruction is in the links of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx only supports websocket starting from 1.3.13. It should be straightforward to set it up. Check the link below:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html